# NestJS: Kafka client - disable consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, kafkajs

I'm trying to produce messages in NestJS with kafka, but it seems the default of the `ClientsModule` is to start consuming a topic and I see no way in the docs to disable that.

Created a client using:

```
    return ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: kafkaOptions,
    });
```

On start I'm getting the following log from kafka:

```
"message":"Consumer has joined the group"
```

even though I didn't configure or request it.

Is there a way to disable the consumer connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start the nestjs kafka without consuming you need to pass the `producerOnlyMode` option as `true`